# phpxlsxwriter insert multiple font style on one cell

Tags: phpxlsxwriter

I need to write row consist of  7 columns to excel and apply two types of font styles, bold and underline on second column only. So, I inserted two styles in array,

```
array('font-style'=>'bold','font-style'=>'underline')
```

But, only font-style underline applied in output file.

```
include_once("vendor/mk-j/php_xlsxwriter/xlsxwriter.class.php");
$writer = new XLSXWriter();
$style_8=array(['halign'=>'right'],array('font-style'=>'bold','font-style'=>'underline'),['halign'=>'right'],['halign'=>'right'],['halign'=>'right'],['halign'=>'right'],['halign'=>'right']);
$writer->writeSheetRow('Sheet1', $rowdata = array('','Amount','','','100.00','','200.00'),$style_8);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since bold and underline from the same category that is font-style,need to write like this

```
 ['font-style'=>'bold,underline']
```

by add to the same key.

```
 $style_8=array(['halign'=>'right'], ['font-style'=>'bold,underline'],['halign'=>'right'],['halign'=>'right'],['halign'=>'right'],['halign'=>'right'],['halign'=>'right']);
```